# PHP Drone.io Cloning Issue

Tags: php, git, github, automated-tests, build-automation

I am attempting to use Drone.io to automate our testing process.

I am trying to use this with two private projects - a toolset and an application.

The toolset works beautifully. Unit tests run, everything works wonderfully.

The application on the other hand clones correctly but then **requires** the toolset as a dependency and is trying to clone that from github.  Both of these are **private** repos.

Right now I have the following line in my `.drone.yml` file.

```
script:
    - git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:fakename/fakeproject.git'
```

Which produces the following error.  Note that the names of the repos are changed to protect my employer.

```
$ git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:fakename/fakeproject.git' '/home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/vcs/fakename-github.com-fakename-fakeproject.git/'
Cloning into bare repository '/home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/vcs/fakename-github.com-fakename-fakeproject.git'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't want to put credentials in the `.drone.yml`, I've tried adding the ssh-rsa of our Drone.io installation to my github account but github tells me the key is already in use. Any help in how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** the original answer was for drone 0.3 which used SSH keys for cloning your repository. Versions 0.4 and higher write an oauth token to a .netrc file to authorize all git+https operations. This means drone clones private repositories out-of-the-box as long as you are using git+https and not git+ssh

---

In this case, you'll need to 1) remove the ssh key from your repository in GitHub and 2) add the SSH key at the user account level in GitHub (https://github.com/settings/ssh). An ssh key at the user account level can clone any repository accessible by your account.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that I want to add the ssh key from the "Public Key, used for Deployments" settings pane in Drone, or a different key?

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you very very much!

Comment: I would say this is hardly a scalable approach. User authorizations for private repos change as people join and leave companies, and CI breaking due to an unauthorized user will produce quite a non-descript error which will be a pain to diagnose. Managing a machine user (or many, if access restrictions are complex) is also a major pain security-wise. What's actually needed is some way to inject multiple deployment keys into the build process, and not have Drone mandate a single key to be used everywhere (as Github deployment keys cannot be reused between repos).